# How to make clang build (like msvc and gcc) with double declared extern "C" functions in different namespaces

Tags: c++, c, clang++

I have this project, where two other projects get included, that provide headers for the same DLL. In one header the declarations are put into a namespace, in the other one not.
That works well for GCC and MSVC, but I can't convince clang to compile it..
So a minimal example would be:

x.h:

```cpp
#include <string>
#if defined __GNUC__
# pragma GCC system_header
#endif // __GNUC__

namespace XX {
  struct Type {
    std::string name;
  };

  extern "C" int Func(Type);
}
```

incl.h:

```cpp
#include <string>
#if defined __GNUC__
# pragma GCC system_header
#endif // __GNUC__

struct Type {
  std::string name;
};

extern "C" int Func(Type);
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include "incl.h"
#include "x.h"

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

G++ complains with a warning, but that is turned off with `# pragma GCC system_header`.
So, how can I get clang to build in an environment like this?

Comment: For me gcc outputs: `warning: conflicting C language linkage declaration 'int Func(Type)'`  I think you are breaking the ODR rule (iirc no diagnostic required).  Live link: https://godbolt.org/z/BDMcc9

Comment: warning or error? and which version?

Comment: yeah.. that warning is _fixed_ by `# pragma GCC system_header` which obviously only works if in a header file.

Comment: Thanks, @eerorika  
That works.. though that's not going to be easily changed (if possible at all).. would there be any other way or is it just _wrong_ to do what is done there?

Comment: @fodinabor *"that warning is fixed"* - not really, it is *disabled* by `#pragma GCC system_header`. The fix here would be to use unique name for each function variant or (if they should refer to the same function) delete one declaration

Answer (score 3):

> [dcl.link] At most one function with a particular name can have C language linkage. Two declarations for a function
>   with C language linkage with the same function name (ignoring the namespace names that qualify it) that
>   appear in different namespace scopes refer to the same function. ...

As such, `::Func` and `XX::Func` must refer to the same function. But your two declarations have different parameter lists - one takes a parameter of `::Type` while the other takes a parameter of `XX::Type`. As such, they cannot be the same function, and thus the quoted rule is violated, and the program is ill-formed.ever

A few ways to fix the program:

- Rename either `XX::Func` or `::Func` so that they are separate functions. Make sure that there is a definition for each.
- In `incl.h`, include `x.h` and replace the definition of `::Type` with `using XX::Type`. So that each `Type` refers to the same type, and consequently both function names refer to the same function. Make sure that there is only one definition.
- In `x.h`, include `incl.h` and replace the definition of `XX::Type` with `using ::Type`. To achieve the same as above.

The latter is by the way how some standard library implementations implement `<cstdlib>` and its friends. They include  the corresponding C standard library header (`<stdlib.h>` in the case of `<cstdlib>`) which declares everything in global namespace (the only "namespace" in C), and then they pick all of the standard functions and types into `std` namespace with `using ::whatever`.

---

P.S. Don't use `#pragma GCC system_header` (unless you're writing a system header). It will suppress *all* warnings (except those produced by `#warning` directive).